Fullcalendar v6 HTTP error 404 when clicking on event
I am using fullcalendar v6 in an asp.net framework environment.
All functions work fine except when i click on an existing event i get the error:
http error 404.0 - Not Found
Requested URL: https://localhost:44372/null
Notification handler: MapRequestHandler StaticFile
This error occurs even when the 'Eventclick' function is not active.

If i put in the eventClick function it runs well but after the function it also runs into the http error 404.0 - Not Found

I have been trying to find a solution for a couple of days now but without success.
Hope anyone can help me with this!
eventually i want to run an eventClick event

Did you specify a url property in the data of the event you're clicking on? There's no other reason that I'm aware of why fullCalendar would respond to an event click in this way. Can you provide a [mre] of the issue please, with relevant code and data - that will make diagnosis a lot easier.

Hi, sorry for my late response. I do use an url for for reading events and resourses. This code used to work fine on a previous version (v4) but i will do a test with some ststic events. This is a real good idea! Thank you. If, i keep running into the same problem i will post my code.

OK. Actually I meant a URL within your event objects. E.g. a propery "url": "https://example.com" within the event data (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing). If you have those in your data, the calendar will try to navigate to the specified URL when the event is clicked.

I fixed the problem in the events handler. I did not use "url:" but i  commented (//) textColor= and backgroundColor= . I filled these variables with =rgb(...,...,...).
This solved my problem. Strange hmmm. Later i will investigate more and i will put my results here. Many thanks for pointing me to the events handler!

That does sound very odd. Maybe raise a ticket with the makers of fullcalendar if you're convinced it's not something you've done wrong

I checked the code again and i found out that i also used the "url:" parameter.
It wasn't filled with any variable and that's why the 'null' error appeared.
Took a lot of time to find this out.
Thanks a lot of pointing me in this direction. Happy coding :-)
